# OXygen Implementation of XQuery: Why Can't Path Expressions Return Attribute Values Directly?

Tags: xquery, exist-db, oxygenxml

Previous Stack questions indicate that in certain implementations of XQuery, returning attributes directly from a path expression (e.g. `$doc//@name') fails to display results and yields runtime errors:

[Can't select XML attributes with Oxygen XQuery implementation; Oxygen XPath emits result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675484/cant-select-xml-attributes-with-oxygen-xquery-implementation-oxygen-xpath-emit/30675592#30675592)

[XQuery unable to select attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308742/xquery-unable-to-select-attribute)

While attribute values **can** be returned using the `string()` or `data()` functions, I'm still confused as to why this limitation exists at all. The former link suggests that it is indeed the OXygen IDE itself, independent of the XQuery processor. However, when I try to return attributes directly I get the following runtime error message:

```
error: Failed to invoke method retrieveFirstChunk in class  org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: org.xml.sax.SAXException: 
Error SENR0001: attribute 'notBefore' has no parent element
```

Since this error message is from the processor, could the type of processor play a role? I'm using eXist-db as my data source and processor.

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducible example? What version of oXygen and eXist are you using?

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of the particular products involved, but the basic situation is that XQuery *can* return an attribute or sequence of attributes, but the standard XQuery 1.0 serialization methods can't display the value. For example a query like //@id will select a sequence of attributes all named "id" and there is no way of serializing this as XML. The "adaptive" serialization method was introduced in XQuery 3.1 largely as a response to this problem: it's designed to display the results in human-readable form, not to output well-formed XML.

Comment: Mike is correct. The issue is with XQuery serialization. Adaptive serialization was just released in eXist 3.3.0 yesterday, so I doubt oXygen support that yet. In the mean time to you need to extract the string value of your attributes using `string(@attr)` to comply with the W3C XQuery serialization specs.